# This.key in React.js 0.12

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With the release of version 0.12 `this.props.key` is no longer available inside a component, however it sounds like you can simply replace that with `this.key` and everything should work as expected.

From the [React v0.12 docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/16/react-v0.12-rc1.html#breaking-change-key-and-ref-removed-from-this.props):

> This means that you need to rename: someElement.props.key -> someElement.key

However when I try to access `this.key` within the render() function of my component, i get an `undefined`.

See my pen to illustrate the issue:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaczr?editors=100

Also:

> Instances of a React Component are created internally in React when rendering. These instances are reused in subsequent renders, and can be accessed in your component methods as this.

How am I supposed to access a component's key?

**UPDATE**

There is [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2429) that clarifies a lot. Thanks to [HEAP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364245/heap) for mentioning it.

Comment: You are not supposed to access the key, this is by design, see [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2429) for more info.

Comment: Why you would want to access the key value? Key is for performance and not for data storage as I understood from docs :)

Comment: Can you point me to the lines in the docs you refer to?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

What the docs actually recommend (although it's badly worded) is that you should treat `key` and `ref` as internal to React and not accessible inside the component.  If you need to know the key, simply pass it as another property with a different name and then access it on `this.props` as normal.

http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/16/react-v0.12-rc1.html#breaking-change-key-and-ref-removed-from-this.props

Quote from above:

> You can no longer access this.props.ref and this.props.key from inside the Component instance itself. So you need to use a different name for those props.

An example would be:

```
<MyComponent key={foo} reactKey={foo} />
```

Then accessing inside as `this.props.reactKey`.

Comment: Yup! Better yet would be to name the additional prop with a name that makes sense for your component. We had one `<EmailSubscription key={...} />` component which used `this.props.key` to specify what key to send to the server in an AJAX request – we changed it to `<EmailSubscription subscriptionKey={...} />` to make it clear what key was used for the server and what key is used for React reconciliation. (Sometimes these actually differ!)

Comment: i am getting error unknown prop when i use react key

Comment: Is it legal in the react world to assign a key as undefined initially?