# Class names for dynamic children React

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic, reactjs, children

I have a set of buttons created from an array, however I'm unsure how to set individual classNames for them. Is there an easy way to this?

```
var ButtonContainer = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    var answerList = this.props.answerList.map(function(input, i){
      return <SingleButton key={'button'+i} singleAnswer={input}/>
    }.bind(this));
    return <div> {answerList} </div>
  }

})

var SingleButton = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button className='quiz-button'>{this.props.singleAnswer}</button>     
      </div>
    )
  }

});
```

I've tried className={this.props.key} but that doesn't seem to work. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since React v0.12 [`key` and `ref` are removed from `props`](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/16/react-v0.12-rc1.html#breaking-change-key-and-ref-removed-from-this.props):

> You can no longer access this.props.ref and this.props.key from inside
>   the Component instance itself. So you need to use a different name for
>   those props.

That is why setting `className={this.props.key}` wont work. But you can try this:

```
return <SingleButton key={'button'+i} className={'button'+i} singleAnswer={input}/>
```

and then

```
<button className={this.props.className}>{this.props.singleAnswer}</button>
```

Related question: [This.key in React.js 0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657023/this-key-in-react-js-0-12)