# How to check if a React component was passed a key prop?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that I want to make sure is rendered with a key. How can I check to see if the component was rendered with a key from inside the component? Its not visible as a prop.

P.S. I could explain why I need to know the key, but that would make this question seem far less simple than it is.

Comment: You could pass in your own key prop like this post recommends:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26664425/3779597

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for the React key though, because I want to prevent componentWillRecieveProps from getting called.

Comment: What do you mean by 'key prop'? There are PropTypes you can utilize that'll warn if your component isn't passed the correct props.

Comment: what do you need it for? as @timthez you can just pass any other prop with the same value as your key

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the render() function, you can call `this._reactInternalInstance._currentElement.key`. I couldn't return `_reactInternalInstance` from the component functions though. In that case, you could set the key, then set a prop called _key with populate it with the same value.

Comment: hmm. well this is good enough for me. I just want to throw a warning anyways. I just have to double check that this works...